# How to get cookies of path domain in subdomain

Tags: php, cookies, session-cookies

I want to get a user cookie in subdomain.

The users are logged in into path domain.
I can get the user cookie when I open example.com/subdomain but I can't get the user cookie when I open subdomain.axample.com because there is no user cookie.

Comment: Kindly, tell us parameters of your setcookie() function.

Comment: the main domain system is php-nuke.

Comment: @header('Set-Cookie: '.$name_data.(($cookietime) ? '; expires='.$expire : '').'; path='.$sitecookies.'; HttpOnly', false);